# JSP connection with DB2 backend

Tags: java, jsp, db2

```
public class Connect {  

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        Connection con=null;
        String db_source="databasesource";
        String db_username="username";
        String db_password="password";
        if(con==null)
        {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:http://localhost:50000/"+db_source,db_username,db_password);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

I've db2 installed in my system.

I've created two applications one a j2se and other jsp ( which runs on tomcat 7 ).

I'am using same code for both j2se and jsp website but this code only works in j2se application, not in the jsp website. I don't know where is the problem.

The error in jsp website is : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`

at line :  `Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();`

I've restarted tomcat many times infact restarted my pc many times. searched the google and found the above code only...

My class Connect is in admin package in the src of the jsp website, I'm using eclipse Indigo for EE.

Any help from anyone will be great...

Thanks in advance.

```
EDIT : I've also added the db2jcc.jar in the projects from build path > add external jar
```

Comment: As @Tomasz and the others have suggested, check that you have added db2jcc.jar to your build path. Make sure that it is there, like creating an instance of that class by yourself in another class and no errors are threw

Comment: Placing the required drives under /WEB-INF/lib works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it cannot find that class. Are you sure that you have all the necessary `*.jar` files in your web application? You could compare the `lib` directory of your J2SE application with the one on your web application.

Comment: I've added the jar file properly in build path... I'm sure there is no problem in the adding jar file.
There is some other problem which i don't understand

Comment: @Pibloo.com: Are you sure that by adding external Jar's they are copied into your application when you deploy? I think you should include your JAR file in your project and link it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If this code works in your J2SE it means you need to have a JAR file somewhere containing `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver` class (*so called* JDBC driver). This JAR needs to be visible in Tomcat. Either add it to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory or to `/lib` directory in Tomcat.

BTW your code need some review: `if(con==null)` is always met, on the other hand if error occurs you are returning `null` - rarely desired. Also read about `DataSource`s concept in Java. Tomcat provides this service out-of-the-box.

Comment: Forgotten to write.. I've added the db2jcc.jar file in projects by adding external jar files in build path...

Answer (score 0):

It seems `DB2Driver` is not available in your `class path`. You can add it into your working application directory or place the `DB2Driver into tomcat lib directory`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

It seems that it cannot find that class. So, I would suggest to place `db2jcc.jar` at physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project. Then using `build path > add jar`

Many times in the past, I have experienced `ClassNotFoundException` if jar is not at physical location. 
Then restarting Tomcat should work.